# Length on input field not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

Despite that I have `>= 2` for the input field, it's on the third keypress thats writes the console message. And if I just use `> 4` I have to enter four letters! Why this and what is wrong with my code?

```
$("#Filter").bind("keypress", function () {

if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {

console.log("OK");

}
});
```

Comment: you can use 'keyup' instead of keypress to get message on entering 2 charectors.

Comment: @AzeezKallayi OK, it's working better with keyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because on `keypress` is executed before the character gets added to the value of the input field.

You can use `keyup` event, the character will be in the value already.

Fiddle:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/f3tcey9c/

Comment: OK, so the solution is just to change the number or is there a better way to improve this code?

Comment: You can use `keyup` event, the character will be in the value already.

Comment: OK, thats better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways, Either changing the character limit or changing the event
Option 1:

```
      $("#Filter").bind("keypress", function () {

       if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {

       console.log("OK");

     }
     });
```

Option 2:

```
$("#Filter").bind("keyup", function () {
if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
console.log("OK");
}
});
```